# What is the command behind the option/shortcut to create new folder in Pantheon Files?

Tags: pantheon-files, keyboard-shortcuts, folder

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> will create a new folder. I would like to use a different (2-key) shortcut.

I know I can use custom shortcuts, but what is the **command** to create a new folder?

Comment: please comment your down-vote and/or flag-to-close, don't let me die in ignorance!

Comment: I can tell you that it was flagged "unclear what you are asking", although I have no idea why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no facility to customize keyboard shortcuts per user within Pantheon Files at present.  If you feel a shortcut is inappropriate or missing in Pantheon Files you could raise a bug about it at https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files.

Note that some system keyboard shortcuts are customizable by going to System Settings/Keyboard.

Update: You could add a custom shortcut in Systems Settings/Keyboard that runs the command "pantheon-files -n". This launches pantheon-files in a new window.

Comment: I was just wandering whether this shortcut was among the ones listed and therefore customizable under System Settings/Keyboards

Comment: I will clarify my question: I don't mean to remove/change the default shortcut Ctrl-Shift-N, but use a new custom shortcut to the same purpose. In fact what I want to know is: **what is the command to create a new folder in Pantheon Files**?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "command" in this context.  The command-line command is "mkdir".  The C command used by Files is g_file_make_directory (GFile *file, GCancellable *cancellable,  GError **error);

Comment: I mean: for the shortcut Ctrl-Shift-N, is there triggered a certain command that I could use with a different custom shortcut to create a new folder?

Comment: would you please write more clearly the command used by Files to create new directory? Is that one command that can be used with a custom shortcut? - I have also asked on U&L: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/279248/32012